# Json_encode no funciona con un array multidimensional

Tags: php, jsonarray

Json_encode me funciona cuando el array es unidimensional, pero cuando es multi, simplemente sucede como si no hubiese escrito el código, el array en cuestion es `$page`:

```
var_dump($page); // array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "/denominaciones/errores" [1]=> string(43) "Errores en la b�squeda de componentes de pc" } }
```

Luego esto lo quiero llevar al javascript:

```
var pagelist = <?php echo json_encode($page)?>;
```

Una ves cargada la pagina en el navegador, voy a la opcion "ver el codigo fuente" y me doy con esta sorpresa:

```
var pagelist = ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claramente no nos estás poniendo el contenido real de tu array, dado que el largo del texto no coincide. Si se replica tu ejemplo literal, la salida no tiene problemas

```
<?php
$code = [ [ 'url', 'contenido' ] ];

echo 'salida de var_dump '.PHP_EOL;
var_dump($code);

echo ' salida de json_encode '.PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($code);
```

[Ver sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c810e436eb07a5d2ab0950472a2670a6a13a479f)

**El contenido real sí es importante**, porque [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) no puede codificar strings que no sean UTF8. En caso contrario, devolverá FALSE. Como más abajo lo intentas escribir, ese FALSE se castea implícitamente como string, y `strval(FALSE)` es justamente un string vacío.

Si estás usando PHP en la versión 7.2 o superior, puedes pasarle un flag para manejar ese escenario. Ej:

```
echo json_encode($code, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

A partir de la 7.3, también puedes decirle que tire una excepción en caso de error:

```
echo json_encode($code, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Lo cual te permitiría saber qué es en particular lo que no logra encodear. Si tu versión de PHP es menor a la 7.3 podrías emular este comportamiento con:

```
$encoded = json_encode($code);
if($encoded === FALSE) {
   throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg());
}
printf('var pagelist = %s;', $encoded);
```

Comment: Edité la publicacion para poner el contenido real, míralo por favor, ¿este "�" puede ser la causa?

Comment: Ya resolví el problema, fui a mi DB de donde provenía el contenido de `$page` y fui al cotejamiento, y en lugar de poner `utf8_unicode_ci` puse el predeterminado `latin1_swedish_ci` y todo me funcionó.

Comment: "�" significa literalmente "no sé con qué reemplazar este garabato"